# Fixed 3 columns layout Zurb Foundation css

Tags: css, stylesheet, html, zurb-foundation

I want to do a **3-col layout** so that:

- Left column contains a fixed / sticky list items
- Left and middle column have fixed known width
- 3rd column must be the left over space; no horizontal bar
- 3rd column will have multiple columns within it and I want to use Foundation framework for the grid (below example shows two large-6 in blue)
- All columns must expand from top to bottom

I want to leverage **Zurb Foundation framework** and reuse as much as I can from the grid framework.

Here is the ideal layout:

[image]

This is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/UUfSF/

```
  <body>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col1 columns'>
          <ul class='sticky'>
              <li>Item 1</li>
              <li>Item 2</li>
              <li>Item 3</li>
              <li>Item 4</li>
              <li>Item 5</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class='col2 columns'>
          <div>Some text 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class='col3 columns'>
          <div class='row'>
              <div class='large-6 columns'>Left</div>
              <div class='large-6 columns'>Right</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The css:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

.sticky{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
}

.col1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: yellow;
}

.col2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;    
}

.col2 div {
    background: red;
}

.col3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.col3 div {
    background: blue;
}
```

There are several problems:

- 3rd column expand over the width of the screen
- None of the columns expand all the way to bottom
- 3rd column's inner columns using large-6 just don't seem to work

Please help fixing the layout issue. Thank you!!

Comment: your jsfiddle is missing external js library - getting thrown error - `ReferenceError: $ is not defined
http://fiddle.jshell.net/qhoc/UUfSF/show/
Line 47`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `width: auto` and it works

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/UUfSF/2/